# How do I compare multiple coefficients of variation?

Tags: statistical-significance, coefficient-of-variation

I have an experiment organized as follows:

- N repeated measures were done for each of M different conditions (each one having a different mean value)
- The experiment was done P times, each time using a different measurement method.

I now want to estimate which of the P methods has the lowest overall coefficient of variation, but I am unsure on how to follow. I initially thought about computing the CV for each of the M conditions (based on the N repeated measures) and then finding the "average" CV for each measurement method. However, in this case I would not know how to test for significance between the different measurement methods.

What would be the best way to show whether a given measurement method has a lower "overall" dispersion than the others with the data I have available?

Comment: If the coefficient of variation really seems useful, that is often a sign that you would be much better off working on log scale, ideally by using a logarithmic link function.

Comment: That makes sense. My problem is that I wanted to compare the spread over different measurements, and it looked a bit heteroscedastic. Even if I use a link function, would that help with my main problem of comparing the different methods?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "[e]ven if" here. With no sight of the data, I can't promise more than I have done. The other side of the argument is that the coefficient of variation can seem a natural summary for distributions like the gamma or lognormal. But inferential procedures for it seem poorly developed. Nevertheless, look for references in Sokal and Rohlf, _Biometry_. Freeman, New York.